# Call/Send SMS with SIM card 1 and 2 with qpython3

Tags: android, python, qpython, qpython3

I have managed to make a call and send an SMS with sl4a for python but it is using the default selected SIM in android system settings.

Is there a way to force SIM 1 or 2 from inside the python code?

```
import sl4a

droid = sl4a.Android()

droid.phoneCallNumber("number") 
#works

droid.smsSend("number", "text")
#works
```

Comment: do you mean that all works?

Comment: Android has no native support for dual sims (yet). It has to be implemented by the vendor and each implementation differs.

Comment: @MEdwin I mean it works for the default selected SIM

Comment: @KlausD.That makes sense. This is a MT65xx phone, but I'm not sure if you can alter settings like that via qpython3

Comment: The ultimate solution for me would be if you could specify when you call the function which SIM to use to dial/send SMS but it looks like this is impossible

Answer (score 0):

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
```

To make a call

```
droid.phoneCall("Phone number")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer might be improved by explaining the code you've given (and how it solves the posters question).